# Lost admin "manage_link" capability WordPress. No "Links" menu item in admin menu

Tags: menus, admin, privileges

Going slightly mad. In the process of upgrading a client's website to WordPress 3.5.1 we've decided to use the built-in WordPress "Links" system to manage their affiliations.

I am using the "Admin Menu Editor" plugin, and I can see the "Links" menu item in there, but it's not showing up in the menu, despite having Administrator privileges. I changed the required capability using this plugin to `administrator` rather than `manage_links` but the attempt to view the Links form gave me the "Cheatin' are we?" page.

I have tried deactivating all plugins, installed the "Capability Manager" plugin to check capabilities - all present and correct, including the necessary `manage_links` privilege.

I've check the database - both `wp_user_roles` in `wp_options` and that the `wp_user_meta` is correct for my login.

What on earth is up?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of badgering about, I discovered this:

If you had no links in your WordPress site prior to upgrading to 3.5.1, you actually need to install a separate plugin to manage your links - Links Manager:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/link-manager/

Job done!